# VueJS: scope.notifications is not a function

Tags: vue.js

I have defined a method in Vue.js 1.0.21 and am getting the following error when trying to use it. *I am using the CLI version so the syntax is a little different than I am accustomed to.*

**Error**

```
TypeError: scope.notifications is not a function. (In 'scope.notifications()', 'scope.notifications' is undefined)
```

---

**Navbar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="navbar">
    <!-- ... -->
    <a href="#data" @click.prevent="notifications()"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i></a>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div> <!-- /navbar -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      versionIsVisible: false,
      version: '2.0.0'
    };
  },

  methods () {
    return {
      notifications: function () {
        console.log('Notifications');
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '../assets/sass/settings';
// ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`methods` shouldn't be a function returning an object. It should be object as stated in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Method-Handler).

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      notifications: function () {
        console.log('Notifications');
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
methods () {
  return {
    notifications: function () {
      console.log('Notifications');
    }
  };
}
```

should be an object of functions, not a function:

```
methods: {
  notifications: function () {
    console.log('Notifications');
  }
}
```